# SonarQube Server 6.1 Error: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x9A S

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

sonarqube runner 2.4 on sonarcube server 6.1 is able to analyse and produce report successfully but server is not able to process the report and throws following error:

> 2016.11.12 13:41:05 TRACE ce[AVhXlYUu6eaRvX5y_I2S][sql] time=265ms | sql=INSERT INTO issues (kee, rule_id, severity, manual_severity,     message, line, locations, gap, effort, status, tags,     resolution, checksum, assignee, author_login, issue_attributes, issue_creation_date, issue_update_date,     issue_close_date, created_at, updated_at, component_uuid, project_uuid, issue_type)     VALUES (?, ?,     ?,     ?, ?, ?,     ?,     ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?,     ?,     ?,?, ?,     ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?) | params=AVhXlgd3R6hiEKFMKI0Y, 417, MAJOR, false, Class "Command" has 34 methods, which is greater than 20 authorized. Split it into smaller classes., 32, [B@51e88e5, 8, 60, OPEN, brain-overload, 12, 56a5cf39bde2227246f55f9c64d17971, 12, 12, , 1478937725000, 1478937725000, -5, 1478938264903, 1478938264903, AVhXcDrFyWOqRIX3Ks1c, AVhXcBE2vDxoF5vpXWIC, 1
>   2016.11.12 13:41:07 ERROR ce[AVhXlYUu6eaRvX5y_I2S][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVhXlYUu6eaRvX5y_I2S
>   org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> #### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #2) failed. 1 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x9A S...' for column 'message' at row 189
>
> #### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #2) failed. 1 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x9A S...' for column 'message' at row 189

System config is 
Centos
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Database sets:

```
mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

For some reason server is trying to insert UTF8mb4 instead of utf-8 characters into table 'issues'.

**Edited 15 NOV 16**

Following JDBC URL is allready added to Sonar runner and sonar server-
*sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar??useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance*

**Please Find Bytes Flow on MySQL Below:**

```
    0, 'Remove this unused "$definition" local variable.', 106,
x'0A08086A106A180C2017',
null, 5, 'OPEN',
'unused', null, '99ac744eeafa6b37f7e8eac5c646437c',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593317, 1479190593317,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYv', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2ZMWzR03Kl-I4i', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "raw_text" 4 times.', 152,
x'0A0A089801109801181B2025120E0A0C120A089801109801181B2025120E0A0C120A0898011098011834203E120E0A0C120A08C20110C201181B2025120E0A0C120A08C20110C2011834203E',
4.0, 10, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '60c1c8e7e300be894ca50e3d8148a45e',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593317, 1479190593317,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYw', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2ZMWzR03Kl-I4j', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "name_width" 6 times.', 38,
x'0A080826102618242030120C0A0A12080826102618242030120C0A0A120808261026183E204A120C0A0A1208083A103A18242030120C0A0A1208083A103A183E204A120C0A0A1208085C105C18542060120C0A0A1208086910691850205C',
6.0, 14, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '8ff134e37a45467429fb6ed08813ef27',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593318, 1479190593318,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYw', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2ZMWzR03Kl-I4k', 475,
'MINOR',
0, 'Remove the literal "true" boolean value.', 195,
x'0A0A08C30110C3011846204A',
null, 2, 'OPEN',
'clumsy', null, 'c24b378689aac9d485209fd0a4e3ade1',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593319, 1479190593319,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYw', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1)
2016-11-15T06:16:33.374835Z    12 Query rollback
2016-11-15T06:16:33.390547Z    12 Query SET autocommit=1
2016-11-15T06:16:35.947505Z    12 Query SELECT 1
2016-11-15T06:16:35.948774Z    12 Query SET autocommit=0
2016-11-15T06:16:35.949893Z    12 Query select

cq.uuid,
cq.task_type as taskType,
cq.component_uuid as componentUuid,
cq.status as status,
cq.submitter_login as submitterLogin,
cq.started_at as startedAt,
cq.created_at as createdAt,
cq.updated_at as updatedAt

from ce_queue cq
where cq.uuid='AVhmn81bDHDOdW61_faq'
2016-11-15T06:16:35.957953Z    12 Query insert into ce_activity (
  uuid,
  component_uuid,
  analysis_uuid,
  status,
  task_type,
  is_last,
  is_last_key,
  submitter_login,
  submitted_at,
  started_at,
  executed_at,
  created_at,
  updated_at,
  execution_time_ms,
  error_message,
  error_stacktrace
)
values (
  'AVhmn81bDHDOdW61_faq',
  'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap',
  null,
  'FAILED',
  'REPORT',
  0,
  'REPORTAVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap',
  'admin',
  1479190500789,
  1479190502631,
  1479190595952,
  1479190595955,
  1479190595955,
  93321,
  '\n### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189',
  'org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: \n### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26)\n  at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:177)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:169)\n    at org.sonar.db.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:41)\n   at org.sonar.db.BatchSession.commit(BatchSession.java:168)\n    at org.sonar.db.BatchSession.increment(BatchSession.java:205)\n at org.sonar.db.BatchSession.insert(BatchSession.java:125)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51)\n   at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)\n  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.insert(Unknown Source)\n  at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PersistIssuesStep.execute(PersistIssuesStep.java:71)\n    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)\n   at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)\n    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)\n   at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:84)\n  at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:57)\n at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35)\n at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)\n  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)\n at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n  at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:127)\n at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:114)\n at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:109)\n at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.commit(BaseExecutor.java:201)\n  at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.commit(CachingExecutor.java:104)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:174)\n    ... 23 more\nCaused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\n   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)\n   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:1161)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(PreparedStatement.java:1582)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1248)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:958)\n  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)\n at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)\n at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)\n   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n   at org.sonar.db.profiling.InvocationUtils.invokeQuietly(InvocationUtils.java:34)\n  at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfilingPreparedStatementHandler.invoke(ProfilingPreparedStatementHandler.java:45)\n at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.executeBatch(Unknown Source)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:103)\n ... 28 more\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)\n  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)\n  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)\n   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)\n  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)\n   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(PreparedStatement.java:1543)\n    ... 39 more\n'
)
2016-11-15T06:16:35.960623Z    12 Query select uuid
from ce_activity
where is_last_key='REPORTAVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap'
  and status <> 'CANCELED'
order by id desc
```

**EDITED 16 NOV 16**

Last few commits of error TABLE 'issues'

```
2016-11-15T06:16:33.100057Z    12 Query commit
2016-11-15T06:16:33.326963Z    12 Query INSERT INTO issues (kee, rule_id, severity, manual_severity,
message, line, locations, gap, effort, status, tags,
resolution, checksum, assignee, author_login, issue_attributes, issue_creation_date, issue_update_date,
issue_close_date, created_at, updated_at, component_uuid, project_uuid, issue_type)
VALUES ('AVhmoExZMWzR03Kl-I0r', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "Australia/Brisbane" 4 times.', 51,
x'0A08083310331826203A120C0A0A1208083310331826203A120E0A0C120A08AF0110AF011826203A120E0A0C120A08A50210A50218242038120E0A0C120A08E30210E302180E2022',
4.0, 10, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '4c83bf60e890268e4c28fc0d535fbead',
null, null,

 '',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593306, 1479190593306,
'AVhmn_WjMWzR03Kl-FYn', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE13MWzR03Kl-I4W', 463,
'MAJOR',
0, 'Remove the unused function parameter "$input".', 191,
x'0A0A08BF0110BF0118312037',
null, 5, 'OPEN',
'cert,misra,unused', null, '2537f941461c393954f764887895a456',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593307, 1479190593307,
'AVhmn_WjMWzR03Kl-FYn', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE13MWzR03Kl-I4X', 463,
'MAJOR',
0, 'Remove the unused function parameter "$output".', 191,
x'0A0A08BF0110BF0118492050',
null, 5, 'OPEN',
'cert,misra,unused', null, '2537f941461c393954f764887895a456',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593308, 1479190593308,
'AVhmn_WjMWzR03Kl-FYn', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE13MWzR03Kl-I4Y', 417,
'MAJOR',
0, 'Class "Command" has 34 methods, which is greater than 20 authorized. Split it into smaller classes.', 32,
x'0A080820102018002005',
null, 60, 'OPEN',
'brain-overload', null, '56a5cf39bde2227246f55f9c64d17971',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593308, 1479190593308,
'AVhmn_WjMWzR03Kl-FYn', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE14MWzR03Kl-I4Z', 486,
'MAJOR',
0, 'Rename "$name" which has the same name as the field declared at line 35.', 520,
x'0A0A0888041088041808200D120C0A0A120808231023180C2011',
null, 5, 'OPEN',
'cert,pitfall', null, '4387290590318a46e73a00de79200861',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593309, 1479190593309,
'AVhmn_WjMWzR03Kl-FYn', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE19MWzR03Kl-I4a', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "format" 4 times.', 41,
x'0A080829102918202028120C0A0A12080829102918202028120C0A0A120808501050181E2026120C0A0A120808551055180C2014120C0A0A120808551055182A2032',
4.0, 10, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '16686315e25cf56e4ddca44fccd55317',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593310, 1479190593310,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYo', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2BMWzR03Kl-I4b', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "format" 4 times.', 72,
x'0A0808481048181E2026120C0A0A120808481048181E2026120C0A0A1208084D104D180C2014120C0A0A1208084D104D182D2035120C0A0A1208085C105C181C2024',
4.0, 10, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '0e27a71d30ca3a85d427d4187dcd2509',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593311, 1479190593311,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYp', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2BMWzR03Kl-I4c', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "namespace" 3 times.', 79,
x'0A08084F104F180C2017120C0A0A1208084F104F180C2017120C0A0A1208084F104F182F203A120C0A0A120808591059181E2029',
3.0, 8, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '1a02bd65046ea1936adb8f6b555770e3',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593312, 1479190593312,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYp', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2QMWzR03Kl-I4d', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "description" 3 times.', 103,
x'0A0808671067180C2019120C0A0A120808671067180C2019120C0A0A120808791079180C2019120E0A0C120A089F01109F01180C2019',
3.0, 8, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '9936da4d327342ba3432096385e745fc',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593313, 1479190593313,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYu', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2QMWzR03Kl-I4e', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "namespace" 3 times.', 64,
x'0A0808401040182D2038120C0A0A120808401040182D2038120C0A0A12080840104018462051120C0A0A120808491049182D2038',
3.0, 8, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '6912cec8ed8dd70391c1cc14d15130d1',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593314, 1479190593314,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYu', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2UMWzR03Kl-I4f', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "<none>" 6 times.', 34,
x'0A080822102218312039120C0A0A12080822102218312039120C0A0A120808251025183F2047120C0A0A1208083210321875207D120C0A0A120808361036183D2045120C0A0A120808601060183E2046120C0A0A120808621062186E2076',
6.0, 14, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '1b6527507aa924b426507804f2901b43',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593315, 1479190593315,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYv', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2UMWzR03Kl-I4g', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "* Description: " 3 times.', 37,
x'0A0808251025180D201E120C0A0A120808251025180D201E120C0A0A120808361036180D201E120C0A0A120808601060180D201E',
3.0, 8, 'OPEN',
'design', null, 'a30f23c3ee9c6650ad296e3e26ec6260',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593316, 1479190593316,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYv', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2UMWzR03Kl-I4h', 468,
'MINOR',
0, 'Remove this unused "$definition" local variable.', 106,
x'0A08086A106A180C2017',
null, 5, 'OPEN',
'unused', null, '99ac744eeafa6b37f7e8eac5c646437c',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593317, 1479190593317,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYv', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2ZMWzR03Kl-I4i', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "raw_text" 4 times.', 152,
x'0A0A089801109801181B2025120E0A0C120A089801109801181B2025120E0A0C120A0898011098011834203E120E0A0C120A08C20110C201181B2025120E0A0C120A08C20110C2011834203E',
4.0, 10, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '60c1c8e7e300be894ca50e3d8148a45e',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593317, 1479190593317,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYw', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2ZMWzR03Kl-I4j', 480,
'CRITICAL',
0, 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "name_width" 6 times.', 38,
x'0A080826102618242030120C0A0A12080826102618242030120C0A0A120808261026183E204A120C0A0A1208083A103A18242030120C0A0A1208083A103A183E204A120C0A0A1208085C105C18542060120C0A0A1208086910691850205C',
6.0, 14, 'OPEN',
'design', null, '8ff134e37a45467429fb6ed08813ef27',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593318, 1479190593318,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYw', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1),('AVhmoE2ZMWzR03Kl-I4k', 475,
'MINOR',
0, 'Remove the literal "true" boolean value.', 195,
x'0A0A08C30110C3011846204A',
null, 2, 'OPEN',
'clumsy', null, 'c24b378689aac9d485209fd0a4e3ade1',
null, null,
'',
1479190059000,1479190059000, null,
1479190593319, 1479190593319,
'AVhmn_WkMWzR03Kl-FYw', 'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap', 1)
2016-11-15T06:16:33.374835Z    12 Query rollback
2016-11-15T06:16:33.390547Z    12 Query SET autocommit=1
2016-11-15T06:16:35.947505Z    12 Query SELECT 1
2016-11-15T06:16:35.948774Z    12 Query SET autocommit=0
2016-11-15T06:16:35.949893Z    12 Query select

cq.uuid,
cq.task_type as taskType,
cq.component_uuid as componentUuid,
cq.status as status,
cq.submitter_login as submitterLogin,
cq.started_at as startedAt,
cq.created_at as createdAt,
cq.updated_at as updatedAt

from ce_queue cq
where cq.uuid='AVhmn81bDHDOdW61_faq'
2016-11-15T06:16:35.957953Z    12 Query insert into ce_activity (
  uuid,
  component_uuid,
  analysis_uuid,
  status,
  task_type,
  is_last,
  is_last_key,
  submitter_login,
  submitted_at,
  started_at,
  executed_at,
  created_at,
  updated_at,
  execution_time_ms,
  error_message,
  error_stacktrace
)
values (
  'AVhmn81bDHDOdW61_faq',
  'AVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap',
  null,
  'FAILED',
  'REPORT',
  0,
  'REPORTAVhmn8tKDHDOdW61_fap',
  'admin',
  1479190500789,
  1479190502631,
  1479190595952,
  1479190595955,
  1479190595955,
  93321,
  '\n### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189',
  'org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: \n### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26)\n  at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:177)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:169)\n    at org.sonar.db.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:41)\n   at org.sonar.db.BatchSession.commit(BatchSession.java:168)\n    at org.sonar.db.BatchSession.increment(BatchSession.java:205)\n at org.sonar.db.BatchSession.insert(BatchSession.java:125)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51)\n   at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)\n  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.insert(Unknown Source)\n  at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PersistIssuesStep.execute(PersistIssuesStep.java:71)\n    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)\n   at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)\n    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)\n   at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:84)\n  at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:57)\n at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35)\n at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)\n  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)\n at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n  at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:127)\n at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:114)\n at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:109)\n at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.commit(BaseExecutor.java:201)\n  at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.commit(CachingExecutor.java:104)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:174)\n    ... 23 more\nCaused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\n   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)\n   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:1161)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(PreparedStatement.java:1582)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1248)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:958)\n  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)\n at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)\n at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)\n   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n   at org.sonar.db.profiling.InvocationUtils.invokeQuietly(InvocationUtils.java:34)\n  at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfilingPreparedStatementHandler.invoke(ProfilingPreparedStatementHandler.java:45)\n at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.executeBatch(Unknown Source)\n    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:103)\n ... 28 more\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: \'\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\x9A S...\' for column \'message\' at row 189\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)\n  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)\n at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)\n  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)\n   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)\n  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)\n    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)\n   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(PreparedStatement.java:1543)\n    ... 39 more\n'
)
```

Comment: I see the "Incorrect string value" in the error message, but not in the "values()"; where is it?

Comment: @RickJames. I could not find the string in values either. I have added last few commits of error TABLE 'issues' with its structure. thx

Comment: None of those hex strings seem to be relevant either.

Comment: @RickJames. Then what could be a solution ? It is the message column in table 'issues'.

Comment: `issues` sounds like a monitoring system, not the real system.  Go back into your code.

Comment: @RickJames. Since source code consists of several files and several lines of code, is there a way to identify in which source code file this error string exists ?  Also I should be looking for  (green heart) right? thx

Answer (score 0):

`\xF0\x9F\x92\x9A` is the utf8mb4 encoding for .  You need to establish that the client has utf8mb4 bytes.

Assuming you are using JDBC, Add `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the JDBC URL.

If there are more issues, please provide more details of bytes as it flows through your system.

Comment: JDBC URL is already there. Please find Bytes flow added in question.

Comment: You have `&characterEncoding=utf8`; I don't know if that spelling is equivalent to `&characterEncoding=UTF-8`.

Comment: I tried with UTF-8. Sonar throws an exception - JDBC URL must have the property 'characterEncoding=utf8'

Comment: It doesn't take that either, it only accepts 'true'.

Comment: Doing a quick search seems to come up with `true` more often than `yes`.  Ditto for `utf8` versus `UTF-8`.  Maybe they spuriously changed the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Rick James, the problem occurs when the message of an issue contains an emoji. The root cause is that tables have the charset named `utf8`... which is not UTF-8 on MySQL. Indeed only `utf8mb4` supports 4-bytes characters like emojis.

As this constraint has major side-effects on the way to design data model on MySQL, fix won't be straightforward. The only workaround is currently to exclude source files with emojis from analysis.

Problem is tracked in https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8496.

Comment: I think Sonar should add utf8mb4 config element as it precedes UTF-8, since symbols are more commonly used nowadays. Anyway, for now I have moved to another database which has the resolved issue. Thanks.

Comment: Using charset utf8mb4 is not only a matter of configuration. It has impacts on the size of columns that are indexed.